# The Bluetooth device name returns null using Bluetooth LE in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to implement Bluetooth LE in my Xamarin forms application. But I'm able to access only the address of Bluetooth devices when the Bluetooth device is discovered. I'm not able to discover the name of the Bluetooth device. I tried various solutions but none of them worked. This is my code

```
 private async void btnScan_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                deviceList.Clear();
                adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.LowLatency;
 adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
                {
                    deviceList.Add(a.Device);


                };

                //We have to test if the device is scanning 
                if (!ble.Adapter.IsScanning)
                {
                    await adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Notice", ex.Message.ToString(), "Error !");
            }
          
        }
```

I don't have any clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try to use `BluetoothDevice.Name` property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.name?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I  tried that but it is coming as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by sending a device name from peripheral. You can advertise Device name in the peripheral.